# Is there any function that will allow me to transform this list into a set of vectors?

Tags: r, list, vector

I would like to turn this list `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` into the following set of vectors

```
(2,3,4) 
(3,4,5) 
(4,5,6) 
(5,6,7)
(6,7,8) 
(7,8,9)
```

Comment: this can be done. are you trying to perform a rolling mean (or similar)? If so, it'll be easier to just use tools for that directly instead, such as `data.table::frollmean`

Comment: Why did you exclude `(1, 2, 3)`  from the output?

Comment: @RonakShah not really, i just forgot to put it there

Answer (score 1):

```
x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
n = length(x)
lapply(1:(n - 2), function(i) x[i:(i + 2)])
```

Comment: I would do `lapply(1:(n - 2), function(i) unlist(x[i:(i + 2)]))` case `x` is actually a list, +1.

Comment: thank you! I did as @jay.sf said since it was a list

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```r
dat <- 1:9
n <- length(dat)
lvl <- 2:(n - 2)
split(dat[lvl + rep(0:2, each = n - 3)], rep(lvl, 3))
#R> $`2`
#R> [1] 2 3 4
#R> 
#R> $`3`
#R> [1] 3 4 5
#R> 
#R> $`4`
#R> [1] 4 5 6
#R> 
#R> $`5`
#R> [1] 5 6 7
#R> 
#R> $`6`
#R> [1] 6 7 8
#R> 
#R> $`7`
#R> [1] 7 8 9
#R>
```